# Reading from a text file and ignoring spaces

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I am reading from a text file that looks like this:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

I will be storing this into a 4x4 char array. My problem is that whenever I am reading from the file it counts the space in between the letters causing it to store the space in the char array. How can i read the line without the spaces? Here is what i have got:

```
char[][] letters = new char[4][4]
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("letters.txt"));
while(read.hasNextLine()) {
    for(int row = 0; row < letters.length; row++) {
        String line = read.nextLine();
        for(int col = 0; col < letters[row].length; col++) {
            letters[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Scanner#next()` to read the characters individually. Whitespace will be skipped.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to get single chars from `line` then use

```
letters[row][col] = line.charAt(2*col);
```

and it will just skip the spaces

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `replace` method that works

```
for(int row = 0; row < letters.length; row++) {
    String line = read.nextLine();
    line = line.replace(" ", "");
    for(int col = 0; col < letters[row].length; col++) {
        letters[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
    }
}
```

This will take your initial `String` and basically remove all the spaces.

This is your input for example :

```
A B C D
```

And here is the output of `line.replace(" ", "")`

```
ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your string obtained from `readLine ()` on the `" "` pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function. It will provide to you to store each line of your file in an array taking as reference the space `" "`. Also, you should declare your `line` variable out of the loop.

For example, if you have your first line: `A B C D`

```
line = read.nextLine(); //Here you read the line

/* Here you store each character of your line in a position of the array 
  because you are taking as reference the space " " */

array = line.split(" "); 

System.out.println(array[0]); //A
System.out.println(array[1]); //B
System.out.println(array[2]); //C
System.out.println(array[3]); //D
```

---

Your code have to look like:

```
char[][] letters = new char[4][4];
String line;
char ch; 
String[] array;
Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("letters.txt"));
while(read.hasNextLine()) {
    for(int row = 0; row < letters.length; row++) {
        line = read.nextLine();
        array = line.split(" ");

        for(int col = 0; col < letters[row].length; col++) {
        {
           ch = array[col].charAt(0);
           letters[row][col] = ch;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful except it won't work because `array[col]` is String[] not char